# For the following recurrence, sketch its recursion tree, and guess a good asymptotic upper bound on its solution.

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, recursion, upper-lower-bounds

T(n) = 4T(n/3)+n
Use the substitution method to verify the upper bound.

I have gotten this far, but I am unsure on how to proceed.
https://imgur.com/a/enxC2s4